# How to view Shortcut steps when a company firewall blocks importing shared Shortcuts

Tags: iphone, shortcuts-app

Is there a website, app or API that I can use to view the contents of a shared iPhone shortcut, and manually enter the steps when my company firewall blocks directly importing the Shortcut?

Comment: If the shortcut(s) are crucial for you to do your job, you might want to ask your IT department to open up the firewall to allow you access, or give you access in some other way. Trying to bypass security at your company may get you in trouble. They are blocking access for a reason, even if it may seem unreasonable to you.